# Do you know of any IDEs that are localized to Spanish?

Tags: localization, ide

I have a buddy that's having a hard time with the language barrier. I tried to think of any IDEs that are also available in Spanish, but couldn't think of any. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought: If someone has trouble with English then the language of the IDE is not his biggest problem if he wants to be a programmer.

Comment: I agree with Sergio Acosta's comment. Joel and Jeff discussed this issue on SO Podcast #48 (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/podcast-48/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio is avaible in spanish
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/default.aspx

Spanish version of the msdn page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vstudio/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) has a spanish language pack [spanish language pack](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/L-3.2_Language_Packs-200607121700/index.php)

Answer (score 3):

[Netbeans is available in spanish too](http://www.netbeans.org/index_es.html)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is available in most "tier one" languages, including Spanish and Japanese. However, not all documentation is translated.